# Using react-router to switch between pages but my props aren't displaying, is this a router version issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

I'm trying to render props with the code I have written however, only my header shows.
My "about" page also displays properly.

This is the warning message that displays when I'm on the home page
"index.tsx:25 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

VScode is also underlining "props", any idea why?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";
import Todos from "./components/Todos";
import AddTodo from "./components/AddTodo";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import "./App.css";

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                exact
                render={(props) => (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
                    <Todos
                      todos={this.state.todos}
                      markComplete={this.markComplete}
                      delTodo={this.delTodo}
                    />
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
              ></Route>
              <Route path="/about" element={<About />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` components no longer have `render` or `component` props, all routes render their components, *as JSX*, on the `element` prop. There is also no longer an `exact` prop as all routes are now always exactly matched.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <React.Fragment>
        <AddTodo addTodo={this.addTodo} />
        <Todos
          todos={this.state.todos}
          markComplete={this.markComplete}
          delTodo={this.delTodo}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

> VScode is also underlining "props", any idea why?

From what I can tell, the `props` aren't being used, so VSCode/linter is likely flagging it as being declared but not used. Hovering over the `props` *should* pop up a small window with the explanation and "buttons" to try and resolve it for you. It's moot though as with what I explained above there is no longer a `render` prop to pass a function to.

Comment: thanks for replying, I see what you mean, I tried to update my code to match yours  and my home page is still not displaying

Comment: and same warning message displays :"index.tsx:25 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

Comment: maybe I might have missed something somewhere else?

Comment: @karinapichardo Oops, so sorry, I got so focused on formatting I forgot to swap `render` to `element`. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
<Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <React.Fragment>
                <AddTodo addTodo={addTodo} />
                <Todos
                  todos={todos}
                  onDelete={onDelete}
                />
              </React.Fragment>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

Also, import this at the start

```
import * as React from 'react'
```